# Searching for the best audit tool

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, auditing

I'm searching an audit tool for SharePoint. I need deep monitoring with detailed information including who, what, when, where, which workstation, and why for change events.

I already found a couple of tools like DELL Change Auditor and Newtwrix SharePoint Auditor, but I would like some advice if you guys have tried them, or another.

Comment: there are also metalogix products, like controlpoint, I was not very fond of it but you might like.

Comment: if you can, write your own application outside SharePoint (like a console app or something).. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should you check also `spdockit` with the following features

[image]

For more details visit  https://www.spdockit.com/ ,

Answer (score 0):

[LOGbinder](https://www.logbinder.com/Products/LOGbinderSP/) is also nice. It extracts SharePoint's audit logs, enhances them by resolving IDs etc and forwards the resulting logs to a SIEM or Windows events.